# Pytest fixtures scoping

Tags: python, pytest

Sorry for this question. It may be repetetive but did not find enough on google related to this. I know fixtures are having 4 scopes (function, module, class, session). Just want to know whether these scopes are valid only if I use `autouse true`?. For `autouse=False`, can i use any fixture having any scope in a test function

Like I am having a `conftest.py` file which is having fixture as

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def test_fixture():
    DO something
    print "Module level fixture am called"
```

`test.py` file is having below data

```
class ABC:
    def test(test_fixture):
        print "Doing something"
    def test_2(test_fixture):
        print "Executing second test"
```

Now If I change `scope` of fixture to `session`, it will still run and produce the same result.

Does that mean scoping only valid if `autouse=True`?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I needed to rename your class to `TestABC`, so that pytest can find it.

Secondly, I will assume that you are using Python 2, but remember that it will no longer be supported in pytest 5.0.

And what I think is your main issue: since your are using a class to group your tests, the first argument to your methods is always the instance itself (aka `self`) even if you give it another name.

That's why pytest is not really detecting that you want to pass the fixture and it never does it.

So try something like this:

```
class TestABC:

    def test(self, test_fixture):
        print "Doing something"

    def test_2(self, test_fixture):
        print "Executing second test"
```

Also note that you don't need to use classes to group your tests, you could use regular functions. So removing the class should also solve your problem:

```
def test(test_fixture):
    print "Doing something"


def test_2(test_fixture):
    print "Executing second test"
```

Also, in your case `module` and `session` will produce a similar effect, since you only have one module (at least in your example).

But you can easily compare with the default scope: if you remove the scope argument completely, the fixture will be called once before each test that requires it.

```
@pytest.fixture
def test_fixture():
    # DO something
    print "Default test level fixture"
```

Using `module` will call it once for the whole module. And `session` would call it once for all the modules.

To answer your original question: no, scopes also apply when `autouse=False`.